# Singular fit for a mixed-effects model with crossed design

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, random-effects-model, crossed-random-effects

I have a dataset where different features were measured for three conditions. Each feature consists of sub-features, and sub-features are nested within features. I'm interested in the contrasts cond1 vs ctrl and cond2 vs ctrl on the feature level. [Here](https://anonfiles.com/58u9Qa9fo5/nested_data_txt) is a part of the dataset (the full data contains ~10k features) and here's an overview of the design: [image]

Each sub-feature has it's own intercept [image] and so I fit a model `readout ~ (1|subfeature) + (condition|feature)`. This gives a *boundary (singular) fit* warning, likely because a corresponding fixed-effects model `readout ~ subfeature + condition:feature` has a non full-rank design.

How can I simplify the mixed-effects model to have a full-rank design? In the fixed-effects only case, I would replace the design matrix columns corresponding to the interaction effects by columns corresponding to the contrasts conditioncond{1|2}_vs_conditionctrl:featuref{1|2}.

Answer (score 2):

If the model matrix for `subfeature + condition:feature` is not of full rank, then I would simply remove `condition` from the random structure.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? If so, please consider marking it as accepted. If not, please let us know why. Thanks !